# AWS C++ SDK UploadPart times out

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am try to upload a file to Amazon S3 using the AWS C++ SDK.

The call to CreateMultipartUpload returns successfully but the following call to UploadPart times out with the following error:

```
(Aws::String) m_message = "Unable to parse ExceptionName: RequestTimeout Message: Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed."
```

I don't understand why the initiate call works but not the part upload call. There clearly isn't any network issue.

This is my code:

```
bool FileUploader::uploadChunk() {

    Aws::S3::Model::UploadPartRequest request;
    request.SetBucket("video");
    request.SetKey(_key);
    request.SetUploadId(_file->uploadId);
    request.SetPartNumber(_file->chunksUploaded + 1);

    long file_pos = _file->chunksUploaded * CHUNK_SIZE;
    _input_file.seekg(file_pos, std::ios::beg);

    _input_file.read(_file_buf, CHUNK_SIZE);
    long n_bytes = _input_file.gcount();

    if(n_bytes > 0) {

        request.SetContentLength(n_bytes);

        char_array_buffer buf2(_file_buf, _file_buf + n_bytes);
        std::iostream *chunk_stream = new std::iostream(&buf2);

        request.SetBody(std::shared_ptr<std::iostream>(chunk_stream));

        Aws::S3::Model::UploadPartOutcome response = _client->UploadPart(request);
        if(response.IsSuccess()) {
            _file->chunksUploaded++;
            _uploader->updateUploadStatus(_file);
        }

        return response.IsSuccess();

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Incidentally, a subsequent call to AbortMultipartUpload succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was my method of obtaining a stream for SetBody. I switched to using the boost library instead of a homegrown approach.

```
    typedef boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> Device;
    boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<Device> stmbuf(_file_buf, n_bytes);

    std::iostream *stm = new std::iostream(&stmbuf);

    request.SetBody(std::shared_ptr<Aws::IOStream>(stm));
```

This works well.

I also needed to keep track of the parts I was uploading for the call to CompleteMultipartUpload as follows:

```
    Aws::S3::Model::CompletedPart part;
    part.SetPartNumber(request.GetPartNumber());
    part.SetETag(response.GetResult().GetETag());
    _uploadedParts.AddParts(part);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the TransferManager interface which will do this for you. It has an IOStream interface. In addition we provide a preallocated buffer implementation for iostream:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-core/include/aws/core/utils/stream/PreallocatedStreamBuf.h